# Select maximum value between 2 same rows MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, max, rows

I have this table here

```
CONCAT(Nome,'',Cognome) Interno value
FRANCESCA BIFULCO       1           0
FRANCESCA BIFULCO       1          84
FRANCESCA BIFULCO       1A        570
FRANCESCA BIFULCO       1A        972
RICCIARDELLI            2        1276
RICCIARDELLI            2        1320
```

All I want to do is to select the maximum value per User. ( As you saw, each user appears multiple times.)

**For Example:**

```
FRANCESCA BIFULCO | 1 | 0
FRANCESCA BIFULCO | 1 | 84
```

**Result wanted:**

```
FRANCESCA BIFULCO | 1 | 84
```

**What I have tried:**

```
select a.ut, max(value)
from (
select Utenti_Condomini.ID_Condominio,CONCAT(Nome,' ', Cognome) as ut, Utenti_Condomini.Interno as i, Greatest(Max(Val_Primo), Max(Val_Secondo), Max(Val_Terzo), Max(Val_Quarto) )as value 
from Letture_Acqua, Utenti_Condomini 
where ID = 19 
and Utente = CONCAT(Nome,' ', Cognome)
and ID = ID_Condominio and Interno = Internus 
group by Utente, Internus, Anno 
order by id_user+0
)a 
group by a.ut, a.i
```

**NOTE:**
The inner query returns what it is shown in the photo.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Give us a sample column names and sample result.  Thanks.

Comment: Done it Mr. Thank you!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you  Mr/Mrs Strawberry for the nice help you provided!

Answer (score 0):

Replace yourTableName with whatever table you're requesting from

```
SELECT CONCAT(Nome,' ',Cognome),interno,MAX(value) FROM yourTableName GROUP BY Nome,Cognome,interno;
```

Comment: Thank you MR. DJ, I edited the question as I have already tried that

Answer (score -1):

**Schema**

```
create table test(
fullname varchar(100),
category char(5),
value int
);
insert into test values("TATA BIRLA", "1",0);
insert into test values("TATA BIRLA", "1",80);
insert into test values("TATA BIRLA", "1A",570);
insert into test values("TATA BIRLA", "1A",972);
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT fullname, max(value)
from test
group by fullname,category;
```

Comment: While this works for a single table, I found out that it does not with joins. Maybe I am missing some referencial integrity rules.

Comment: Fetch all rows with the same set of columns and wrap it by group by clause.  Example:  select x.fullname, max(x.value)
from (
 select fullname, value,category from test
 union
 select 'IMS' as fullname, 90 as value, '1B' as category from dual
) x
group by x.fullname,x.category;